# Why chrome extension sandbox page block loading external script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I want to load some external scripts in a sandbox page and then on event page uses message passing to communicate with the sandbox page to use those scripts. I am basically following these two documentations:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox

This is the **manifest.json** I use with the sandbox and event page config:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Diver",
    "description": "Diver",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "minimum_chrome_version" : "57",
    "background": {
        "page": "eventpage.html",
        "persistent": false
    },
    "sandbox": {
        "pages": ["sandbox.html"]
    }
}
```

This is the **eventpage.html**, which loads the sandbox.html in an iframe:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe id="sandboxFrame" src="sandbox.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the **sandbox.html**, which loads an external script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/5.2.3/ajv.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I try it I am getting an error saying the loading of the external script is blocked by content security policy. So looks like this is not allowed according to the doc:

"Starting in version 57, Chrome will no longer allow external web content (including embedded frames and scripts) inside sandboxed pages. Please use a webview instead"

"Also, the CSP you specify may not allow loading external web content inside sandboxed pages."

The doc asks me to use webview but webview is only available in Chrome App. Next I upload sandbox.html into a cdn and replace it in the eventpage.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe id="sandboxFrame" src="https://www.somecdn.com/sandbox.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

The external script loads this time, probably because that external page doesn't have the CSP blocking the script.

I don't understand why the same script is blocked when used in sandbox.html in the extension but not when sandbox.html is loaded from an external domain. I know it's because of CSP, but why do Chrome decided to block it this way. I tested it in Chrome 56 and it's not blocked. Only after Chrome 57 it's blocked.

Comment: After reading your question, I can't really discern what is it that you're asking.

Comment: @Xan Sorry the question makes it confusing. I have added code samples and edited the question. Please have a look again. Thanks.

Comment: No-no, I understand your situation (though code is welcome). But what kind of answer are you looking for? What is your _question_?

Comment: “Why chrome extension sandbox page block loading external script?” I just want to confirm my finding is correct, and understand the security concern behind this change to block external script in sandbox page.

Comment: OK, so you're asking "why this was changed". Gotta find the Chromium commit then..

Comment: This is the chromium commit I found: https://codereview.chromium.org/2563843002
It doesn't say why it's changed too. At the bottom of the thread, it says it only applies to chrome app, but that's not true, the change apply to both app and extension.

Comment: It might be a bug then!

Comment: Yeah probably not gonna get an answer here. Created a bug report in Chromium to see if they have an answer: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=770271